# Master/detail clientdatasets with masters on different descendant datamodules: how to refer to them from code?

Tags: delphi, inheritance

I have a data module `TDataModuleBasis` with a TClientDataSet named `RequestData`.

I have two datamodules descending from `TDataModuleBasis` with both an additional TClientDataSet,
let's name them `TDataModuleTasks1` with `Task1Data`, and `TDataModuleTasks2` with `Task2Data`.

Tasks have requests, so `RequestData` is the detail table for either `Task1Data` or `Task2Data`.
`Task1Data` and `Task2Data` have a persistent field pointing to the query for `RequestData`, the queries behind these TClientDataSets are set up for the proper master/detail relation (these queries are actually in a server application which we connect to).

My forms have a generic TDataModule property named `EditDataModule` that is always set up to point to the required data module for the form,
so my code on Form1 refers to `TDataModuleTasks1(EditDataModule)`, and on Form2 refers to `TDataModuleTasks2(EditDataModule)`.

I now have FormX that is created/used from either Form1 or Form2, that needs to use `RequestData` and `Task1Data`/`Task2Data`.
After creation, I set `FormX.EditDataModule := Form1.EditDataModule` or `FormX.EditDataModule := Form2.EditDataModule`.

Now, when I want to use `RequestData` in FormX, I can do that in code as `TDataModuleBasis(EditDataModule)`, because TDataModuleBasis is the ancestor of both `TDataModuleTasks1` and `TDataModuleTasks2`.

But I also need to access the master clientdataset, let's say it's a property `FTaskDataSet`.
I did it with

```
if (EditDataModule is TDataModuleTasks1) then
   FTaskDataSet := TDataModuleTasks1(EditDataModule).Task1Data
else   
   if (EditDataModule is TDataModuleTasks2) then
      FTaskDataSet := TDataModuleTasks2(EditDataModule).Task2Data
   else
      Assert(error);
```

Question:

Is there a more 'generic' way to refer to the master datasets without the `is` tests and casts? Can I e.g. reach them from `RequestData`?

[BTW Actually, my `Task1Data` and `Task2Data` are both named `TaskData`, but I gave them separate names here.]

Comment: If you're using purely code to access the datasets you could expose them as properties with a virtual function getter, then override that function in the descendant class. You can then use `EditDataModule.TaskData` and polymorphism will handle the rest.

Comment: @Andy_D Why didn't I think of that? ;-) Smart, thanks. But http://stackoverflow.com/users/624696/the-alien beat you to it in writing an actual answer.

Comment: Nothing to stop me adding my comment as an answer and you accepting it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to Write a property to TDataModuleBasis class as

```
TDataModuleBasis = class(TDataModule)
protected
  function GetTaskData: TClientDataSet; virtual; 
public
  property TaskData: TClientDataSet read GetTaskData;
end;
```

Then override the base `function GetTaskData: TClientDataSet;` in TDataModuleTasks1 and TDataModuleTasks2 where function returns the appropriate TClientDataSet like

```
TDataModuleTasks1 = class(TDataModuleBasis)
private
....
protected
  function GetTaskData: TClientDataSet; override;
public
....
end;

....

function TDataModuleTasks1.GetTaskData: TClientDataSet;
begin
  Result := (*the client data set object*)
end;
```

One other way could be to declare a FTaskClientDataSet field and introduce a constructor (or again a property) in TDataModuleBasis then access the Task set through.

Thus, you can be able to access the TaskData with `TDataModuleBasis(RequestData.Parent).TaskData`

Comment: Your first method gives me the [X1020 Constructing instance of '%s' containing abstract method '%s.%s'](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/X1020_Constructing_instance_of_%27%25s%27_containing_abstract_method_%27%25s.%25s%27_%28Delphi%29) error and I'm not willing to disable those warnings with {$WARN CONSTRUCTING_ABSTRACT OFF}.
I have left the `abstract` out, it is not necessary for he solution.

Comment: Also, your alternate placement in the protected/private section leads to the [X2269 Overriding virtual method has lower visibility](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/X2269_Overriding_virtual_method_%27%25s.%25s%27_has_lower_visibility_%28%25s%29_than_base_class_%27%25s%27_%28%25s%29_%28Delphi%29) hint. I have placed both in the protected section.
I have edited your answer accordingly.

Comment: I first left abstract out but thought about what if Basis.Get function left empty if it isn't abstract. Since when there's a call to Derived.Get if Basis.Get is abstract and not overridden in Derived there'll be an abstract error and people should say "oh, i should have overridden it". That was my point for abstract =) As visibility lovering, that was on purpose in first, thinking there would be no need to derive from TDataModuleTasksN. But this way it has more flexibility since there can and/or needed to types be derived from TDataModuleTasksN if desired.